# Android history only for 1 activity

Tags: android

I would like to know if it's possible to keep only 1 of each activity in history? I have tab-like interface and when user goes between activities it remembers them in history.

I tried noHistory attribute but it will cause activities to not go into history at all.
Ideally I'd like to have history but make it work like this:

Scenario:
Act1->Act2->Act1->Act2

In "standard" setup when clicking "back" it will unwind like
Act1->Act2->Act1->GONE

In "noHistory" mode it when click "back" it will be:
GONE

I want only 1 copy of each in stack, so it will be:
Act1->GONE

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `startActivity()`, add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to the `Intent`. That will reuse your existing activity instance.

Comment: Thanks! But I got another issue.. I call activity with putExtra and this data get's lost when I add setFlags to intent. How do I use both?

EDIT: Actually, I know why, it's the same activity with different input. I want activity to RESTART and stay on top. Right now it's just pulling that activity and reorder it to top, but I can't pass parameters to refresh

Comment: @katit: For that, you may need to switch to `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` instead of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

I think you may want

android:launchMode="singleTop"

in your activity's manifest if I understand your needs correctly